# Use Linq to query in order except the one record

Tags: linq

I have one table in my DB containing set of names. I need to use order by condition to sort the names alphabetically except one name which should print on top of the list if the user name is Say 'John'. I got one SQL query, but
How do i use this following query in linq?

```
SELECT name
FROM names
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN name = 'John' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
name
```

Comment: you can achieve this by getting the result without jhon sorted union join and combine the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = db.names.Where(x => x.Name == "John")
                     .Concat(db.names.Where(x => x.Name != "John")
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it this way:

```
var result =
    db.names
        .ToArray()
        .OrderBy(x => (x.Name == "John" ? "0" : "1") + x.Name)
        .ToArray()
```

Comment: Nice one @Enigmativity +1 :) I think it will just do 1 loop iteration. Isn't it..?

Comment: @RahulSingh - Effectively, yes. The `OrderBy` is probably O(nlogn) though.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

```
var listWithoutJohn=db.names.Where(t=>t.name!="John").OrderBy(t=>t.name).ToArray();
var johnList=db.names.Where(t=>t.name=="John").ToList();
var result=johnList.AddRange(listWithoutJohn);
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Hadi, i will check it in that way.